# Call the interface method after execution of a method in that interface dynamically

Tags: spring, annotations, aop, spring-aop

First of all sorry for the title i have put,i just couldn't put it all in the title.
Here is my scenario:

i have a method deleteSomething() in each of my interface.After add/update/delete the deleteSomething() should be called. Now i don't want to do something like this

```
public void add(MyOblject objToSave)
{
  sampleRepository.save(objToSave);
  deleteSomething();
}
```

i want, after my add() method is executed successfully call the deleteSomething() method of that interface ,of which the add() method was executed. 
This may be possible using aop or annotations but i don't know how to proceed with it.So please suggest me ways to achieve this.

I am using spring data jpa+hibernate

Comment: You can do that albeit a little hack. An `@AfterReturning` is the advice that you need. So look up on Spring AOP to check how do you write them. For the `deleteSomething()` you would have to use Reflection to invoke the method through the aspect. But the elephant in the room would be, what transaction boundary are you looking at?

Comment: sorry, but i didn't get what u mean by "transaction boundary". Would you tell me what you meant by that?

Comment: what i mean by that is, when you want to call your `delete()` method after your business logic of `add()` is executed, it no longer will be within the same transaction, if your transaction begins from the execution of the `start()` method and finishes post that method execution.